# How to get the client IP adress using HTTP.jl

Tags: http, tcp, ip, julia, webserver

I'm trying to get the both the client request and IP address from http requests to my `HTTP.jl` server (based on the [basic server example in the docs](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/examples/#Simple-Server)).

```
using HTTP
using Sockets

const APP = HTTP.Router()

# My request handler function can see the request's method
# and target but not the IP address it came from
HTTP.@register(APP,"GET","/",req::HTTP.Request -> begin
    println("$(req.method) request to $(req.target)")
    "Hello, world!"
end)

HTTP.serve(
    APP,
    Sockets.localhost,
    8081;
    # My tcpisvalid function can see the client's
    # IP address but not the HTTP request
    tcpisvalid=sock::Sockets.TCPSocket -> begin
        host, port = Sockets.getpeername(sock)
        println("Request from $host:$port")
        true
    end
)
```

My best guess would be that there's a way to parse the `TCPSocket.buffer` into an HTTP request but I can't find any methods to do it.

Can you suggest a way to get an `HTTP.Request` from a `TCPSocket` or a different way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you may want to open an issue/feature request for HTTP.jl. Many frameworks like this would send that sort of extra metadata along with the request as "REMOTE_ADDR", maybe HTTP.jl should do the same.

Comment: Good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The router (`APP`) is a (collection of) "request handler(s)" which can only access the `HTTP.Request` -- you can not get the stream from it. Instead you can define a "stream handler", which is passed the stream. From the stream you can get the client's IP adress using [`Sockets.getpeername`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Sockets/#Sockets.getpeername) (requires HTTP.jl version 0.9.7 when called on a `HTTP.Stream` as in the examples below).

```
using HTTP, Sockets

const APP = HTTP.Router()

function request_handler(req::HTTP.Request)
    println("$(req.method) request to $(req.target)")
    return "Hello, world!"
end

HTTP.@register APP "GET" "/" request_handler

function stream_handler(http::HTTP.Stream)
    host, port = Sockets.getpeername(http)
    println("Request from $host:$port")
    return HTTP.handle(APP, http) # regular handling
end

# HTTP.serve with stream=true to specify that stream_handler is a function
# that expects a HTTP.Stream as input (and not a HTTP.Request)
HTTP.serve(stream_handler, Sockets.localhost, 8081; stream=true) # <-- Note stream=true

# or HTTP.listen
HTTP.listen(stream_handler, Sockets.localhost, 8081)
```